# Extract last email with gscript

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail, trim

I have the following code with which I have to extract the last email arrived with the label 'AlertGol', then I have to process it by cutting the parts that I do not need and send it back to me by email. Something I'm doing wrong because I get more than 3 emails including one undefinied.

```
 function getEmails() {
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("AlertGol");
  var thread = label.getThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < thread.length; i++) {
  var messages = thread[i].getMessages();
  for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++)
    {
      var msg = messages[j].getPlainBody();
      var trim = msg.substring(5,15);
      var trim1 = msg.substring(40, 90);
      var tot = trim+trim1;
    }
  GmailApp.sendEmail(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(), 'Subject', tot);
}
```

Comment: Double check your indentation levels. In the Script Editor, highlight all your code and press Tab to auto indent based on syntax. You can easily spot incorrectly positioned braces that way.

Comment: It seems to work but it takes all the emails with the same label, I do not know how to do to get the last email arrived